# rxjs isStopped is deprecated

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

We have the following method in our code:

```
private createChart(dataset: any): any {
        if (!this.unsubscribeAll.isStopped) {
            this.chart = this.miStockChartService.createChart(dataset, this.chartId, this.options, this.extendOptions);
            this.showLoader = false;
            return this.chart;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Visual Studio Code says that isStopped is deprecated in the next version of rxjs. How do I rewrite this so that it's compatible with the next version?

Comment: If you want to check if all the subscriptions have been unsubscribed. Then you can use the `closed` property?

Comment: It looks like `unsubscribeAll` is a `Subject` so you could use `closed` https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/3d062a2b8c2e49efc92e1205ae926c7182745b8c/src/internal/Subject.ts#L18-L26

Comment: thanks, closed did the trick! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your replacement to 'isStopped' depends on your strategy.

- When a subject is **stopped**, it means that the subject has **temporarily** stopped (paused) emitting values.
- When a subject is **closed**, it signifies that the subject should have reached a **permanent** end state and would no longer emit any more values.

Generally a subject is marked as **stopped** as soon as it is called `complete()` and as **closed** when the subject itself forces `unsubscribe()` internally. See you can have a subject that is in stopped state, but not closed and it won't emit any value.

**An option to circumvent this:**

You can use, if it fits your strategy, types of subjects that are not marked as stopped on completion. Up to version 6 of Rxjs, ReplaySubject doesn't stop on completion (this is not true from version 7 on).

```
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

const replaySubject = new ReplaySubject<number>(2); // Store the last 2 emitted values

replaySubject.next(1);
replaySubject.next(2);
replaySubject.complete(); // Complete the ReplaySubject
replaySubject.next(3); // emiting after completion 

const observable = replaySubject.asObservable();

observable.subscribe({
  next: value => {
    console.log(`Observable received value: ${value}`);
  },
  complete: () => console.log('Completed')
});

// Outputs two last values:
// Observable received value: 2
// Observable received value: 3
// Completed
```

**Another option:**

If your strategy uses subjects with regular behavior, as described in the beginning of this response, you can either subscribe direct to the subject, so it turns 'stopped' flag to *false*, or just assign a new subject to it, since theoretically there is no observer watching it:

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';

let behaviorSubject = new Subject<number>();
let observable = behaviorSubject.asObservable();


console.group('OPEN AND RUNNING');
let subscription = observable.subscribe({
  next: value => console.log(`Subscp 1 received value: ${value}`),
  complete: () => console.log('Complete 1')
});
behaviorSubject.next(1); // Value is received in subscription 1
subscription.unsubscribe(); // no effect on subject; subscription 1 just won't receive any more values
// by now behaviorSubject is not closed neither stopped
console.log(`Stopped: ${behaviorSubject.isStopped}; Closed: ${behaviorSubject.closed}`);
console.groupEnd();


console.group('OPEN BUT STOPPED');
behaviorSubject.complete();
// now, after completion, behaviorSubject is stopped, but not closed
console.log(`Stopped: ${behaviorSubject.isStopped}; Closed: ${behaviorSubject.closed}`);
if(behaviorSubject.closed) {
  // whatever is here, won't be executed
} else {
  behaviorSubject.next(2);
  console.log('Value 2 won\'t be received, subject is complete/stopped');
}
observable.subscribe({
  next: value => console.log(`Subscp 2 received value: ${value}`),
  complete: () => console.log('Complete 2 anyways')
});
console.groupEnd();


console.group('CLOSED AND STOPPED');
behaviorSubject.unsubscribe();// closes subject
try {
  console.log('Subscription 3 won\'t receive value neither complete; no error thrown as well');
  observable.subscribe({
    next: value => console.log(`Subscp 3 received value: ${value}`),
    complete: () => console.log('Complete 3'),
    error: err => console.log(err)
  });
  behaviorSubject.next(3);
} catch(err) {
  console.log(`RxJs just threw error: ${err}`);// ObjectUnsubscribedError: object unsubscribed
}
console.groupEnd();


console.group('NEW SUBJECT')
behaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(4); // fresh and open instance of a subject
observable = behaviorSubject.asObservable(); // getting an observable representation of the open subject
observable.subscribe({
  next: value => console.log(`Subscp 4 received value: ${value}`),
  complete: () => console.log('Complete 4')
});
console.groupEnd();
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

"closed" did it and solved the problem

Comment: hey @Erwin1441 thanks for letting us know it worked for you; it doesn't always work, so I provided a complete answer with some scenarios. Hope it helps you on future issues or challenges, as well as it helps more people.